# Click Listener causing unable to start activity nullpointer exception

Tags: android

I've been struggling with this issue all day in a larger project. I wrote a test app to rule out it being caused by my data objects etc. But I am getting the same results.  Everything in this app is more or less the boilerplate provided by android studio and examples taken from the developer documentation. the min SDK is 4.0 and I am compiling it with 4.3.

```
    package com.testapp.testapp;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ActionBar;
        import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView MyTextview;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
            Button MyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
            MyTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            final View.OnClickListener Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.mybutton:
                            MyTextview.setText("Test");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            MyButton.setOnClickListener(Click);
        }
        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

fragment_main.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Stacktrace

```
11-04 15:47:08.396  21228-21228/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp.testapp/com.testapp.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5256)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.testapp.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2290)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5256)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: null pointer caused by line 39. Which line is this? too hard to tell from the code.

Comment: MyButton.setOnClickListener(Click);

Comment: Did you implement the `Click OnClickListener` for the button? I don't see any of this code. Nvm i see it now

Comment: You cannot declare a listener like you have. The listener is created before you set it for your view. In otherwords before you actually create the listener you must call setOnClickListener(Click) before actually implementing the method on your button

Comment: do something like `myButton.setOnClickListener(Click);` then create this method `OnClickListener Click = new OnClickListener(){ @Override public void onClick(View v){ }};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for the correct things in the wrong place. What you are looking for (`findViewById`) belongs to the fragment view hierarchy, not to the activity. Override `onActivityCreated` inside the fragment, and move the `findViewById` you do in the `Activity` onCreate, inside it

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Button MyButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
             MyTextview = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            final View.OnClickListener Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.mybutton:
                        MyTextview.setText("Test");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
            MyButton.setOnClickListener(Click);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

remove the snippet of code from your activity`s onCreate and run it again

Comment: is right. I would also recommend offloading adding listeners inside `onCreateView()` this method should do nothing more than initialize and return the root view. Add the rest of the listeners in your `onCreate()` or `onActvityCreated()` methods of the `Fragment` class

Comment: better than onActivityCreated is onViewCreated for this purpose

Comment: It Pretty Much boils down to I had no understanding of how fragments worked. I did not even realize I was dealing with fragments.

Comment: i don't see this method `onViewCreated()` in the `Fragment` class

Comment: yeah fragments are very powerful but can be pretty tricky to work with.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle) @inner_class7

Comment: never used this method before. didn't know it existed. I would inflate my layouts using the `onCreateView()` method and handle the rest of the UI stuff in the too above methods. Thanks I will have to look into using this!